# Awk merge files with repeat lines

Tags: awk

First of all, sorry for my English (it's my first time on StackOverflow). I am trying to mix two files with `awk` and I have tried the following:

File 1:

```
49:6:2:8:5
46:8:3:6:15
47:8:5:6:104
6:3:10:8:3
48:6:1:10:2
```

File 2:

```
1:admin:admin:00000000A:admin@a:admin:admin
3:b:b:66666666b:b@b.b:bb:bb
4:w:w:22222222w:w@w.w:ww:ww
5:r:r:44444444r:r@r.r:rrr:rrr
6:ga:ga:55555555g:g@g.g:gg:gg
7:e:e:33333333e:e@e.e:ee:ee
8:u:u:77777777u:u@u.u:uu:uu
9:james:lopez:12312312a:jose@gmail.com:jose:perez
10:luois:asd:12312312a:jj@j.j:ju:an
```

Output:

```
6:3:10:8:3:b:b
48:6:11:10:2:ga:ga
47:8:5:6:104:u:u
```

Command used:

```
awk -v OFS=: 'NR==FNR { a[$2]=$0; next }$1 in a { print a[$1],$2,$3}' FS=: File1 File2
```

Expected output: In file one, column 2 and 4 are the IDs of file two, and in file two I added columns 2 and 3. Some must be in two or more rows.

```
6:3:10:8:3:b:b:u:u
48:6:11:10:2:ga:ga:admin:admin
47:8:5:6:104:u:u:ga:ga
49:6:2:8:5:ga:ga:u:u
46:8:3:6:15:u:u:ga:ga
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F: -v OFS=: 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 OFS $3; next} {print $0, a[$2], a[$4]}' f2 f1
49:6:2:8:5:ga:ga:u:u
46:8:3:6:15:u:u:ga:ga
47:8:5:6:104:u:u:ga:ga
6:3:10:8:3:b:b:u:u
48:6:1:10:2:ga:ga:luois:asd
```

The second file is read first to create the mapping. First field is used as key and second and third field contents are saved with OFS in between as separator. When the first file is read, print line content, and then get content based on 2nd and 4th field as key from the array.

Note that your expected output shown in the question doesn't match for `48:6:1:10...` line, perhaps you read `10` as `1` or something.